# Structured Theorems(Programs) in Number Theory Proving Logical Conjunctions Using Infinite Descent

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, soft-question, computer-science, infinite-descent

> Any comments/answers concerning the block-quote (red) text would be appreciated.

---

I've been examining proofs of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic and constructing my own using the [method of infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent).

As I work on this it reminds me of theory of [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming), regarding all the infinite descent proofs as code fragments.

> I now believe any selection of these infinite descent proofs could be combined into one theorem that would 'crank it all out' together, with all the results being  *subtheorems.*

The universal quantifier distributes over conjunciton and to prove, say

$$ \forall n\, P_1(n) \land \forall n\, P_2(n) \land \forall n\, P_3(n) \land \forall n\, P_4(n)$$

the infinite descent machinery would be applied to

$$ \exists n\, \neg P_1(n) \land \exists n\, \neg , P_2(n) \land \exists n\, \neg  P_3(n) \land \exists n\, \neg  P_4(n)$$

and the proof would be structured into cases but with a 'program flow'.

---

Here is a simple example of using infinite descent thinking along these terms, tackling a problem that usually is set up with weak induction and a base case.

$\quad S(n) : \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{(n+1)n}{2}$

$\quad P_1(n) : \forall n \ge 1\; \text{ If } n = 1 \text{ then } S(n) \quad$ (induction base case expressed here as a tautology)

$\quad P_2(n) : \forall n \ge 1\; S(n)$

Case 1: Return $P_1(n)$ as True.

Case 2:

Let $n \ge 1$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^n k \ne \frac{(n+1)n}{2}$. Since $P_1(n)$ is true, $n \gt 1$. It is easy to show that $S(n-1)$ is also false and $n -1 \ge 1$.

Return $\neg P_1(n-1)$ as True.

Program Execution Ends: $\forall n \ge 1 \; P_1(n) \land P_2(n)$ is TRUE.

---

> I know that computers are proving theorems, and was wondering if this might be applicable.